# Nested GridViews

Tags: c#, gridview

I'm working on nested Gridview with 2 lists of which now I've to bind the value of title field of parent Gridview to the child Gridview column whenever a new entry is to be done.

For example: I have to insert a new entry for child list then it should bind the `ID` value of parent list in one of is column in order to let us know to which row it belongs.

Comment: Easily you can find many example ,try this http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: What you have tried so far. Please post some source code and tell us where you got stuck.